# How to build GNU Hello .deb?

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, packaging

I can't seem to work out how to build [GNU Hello on Ubuntu 22.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/hello). To reproduce, start a Docker container using `docker run --interactive --rm --tty ubuntu:22.04`, then run the following:

```bash
apt-get update
apt-get install -y debhelper-compat dpkg-dev wget
cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/hello/hello_2.10.orig.tar.gz http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/hello/hello_2.10-2ubuntu4.dsc http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/hello/hello_2.10-2ubuntu4.debian.tar.xz
tar -xf hello_2.10-2ubuntu4.debian.tar.xz
mkdir hello_2.10-2ubuntu4
mv debian hello_2.10-2ubuntu4
cd hello_2.10-2ubuntu4
dpkg-buildpackage
```

At this point I get this error message:

> cp: cannot stat 'NEWS': No such file or directory

followed by

> dh_installdocs: error: cp --reflink=auto -a NEWS debian/hello/usr/share/doc/hello returned exit code 1

What am I doing wrong? Where is the `NEWS` file supposed to be? The build is aware of the upstream tarball ("dpkg-source: info: building hello using existing ./hello_2.10.orig.tar.gz"), do I need to manually unpack that?

Comment: Can you compare your results with the source tree that `apt-get source hello` produces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to extract the main tarball too:

```
tar xf hello_2.10.orig.tar.gz
cd hello*/
tar xf ../hello_2.10-2ubuntu4.debian.tar.xz
dpkg-buildpackage
```

`apt-get source hello` will take care of downloading and extracting the source package for you (if the source repositories are configured), and `apt-get build-dep` will take care of the build dependencies:

```
apt-get update
apt-get source hello
apt-get build-dep hello
cd hello*/
dpkg-buildpackage
```